# Binding Object to Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm making a project on Student Management System. i have used Linked List to save my data and created the linked list by myself. i want to know how to bind linked list to the Data-grid.

The Linked List Code is here:

Node Class :

```
public class StudentData 
{
    private string nameStudent;
    public string NameStudent
    {
        get { return nameStudent; }
        set { nameStudent = value; }
    }

    private string fathernameStudent;
    public string FathernameStudent
    {
        get { return fathernameStudent; }
        set { fathernameStudent = value; }
    }

    private UInt32 seatNumberStudent;
    public UInt32 SeatNumberStudent
    {
        get { return seatNumberStudent; }
        set { seatNumberStudent = value;  }
    }

    .......
}
```

List class :

```
class StudentManagment
{
    private StudentData first;
    internal StudentData First
    {
        get { return first; }
        //set { first = value; }
    }

    public void addANewStudent(string name, string fathername, ...... ,  string school)
    {
        StudentData newlyCreatedStudent = new StudentData(name, fathername,.....,school);
        newlyCreatedStudent.Next = first;
        first = newlyCreatedStudent;
    }   
}
```

first contains the reference of the first node in the list.

how can i bind this to data grid view so i can display it in window.

Comment: See the *Binding to Collections* section in the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) article on MSDN. Also worth reading: [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Above all, you won't implement your own list. Use an [ObservableCollection<StudentData>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.